# how do you turn off smart brackets//parenthesis in prelude

Tags: init-file, prelude, ruby-mode

I hate it when prelude auto adds the ending `}` when I type `{`
(this is ruby mode)

This is very common, for example typing `(` auto adds a `)`
This is really annoying when trying to edit code, or a lot of copy/pasting.

I want emacs/prelude to permanently not do this kind of thing. I have started customizing `~/.emacs.d/personal/personal.el` for other things, but not sure how I should go about getting this done.

Comment: Could you be more specific in the title of the issue? Something like "Prelude: do not add closing pair", for instance.

Comment: You could try `(smartparens-global-mode -1)` in your personal configuration.

Comment: You are, or Prelude is perhaps, imposing this hair shirt on yourself. Emacs does not do that by default. You might consider just using `show-paren-mode` and foregoing the eager insertion of balanced delimiters. 

(That's a holdover from non-/pre-Emacs 1980s "structured editing", IMHO. The idea was to never let you do anything in an editor that would at any moment allow code to have invalid syntax. Some XML editors still impose this, but they usually give you a way to opt out, either by config or on the fly.)

Comment: Please change the title of the question to something informative about the content of the post.  A rant in place of an informative question title is counterproductive.

Answer (score 1):

Try this too

```
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'turn-off-smartparens-mode)
```

Comment: Why only in `ruby-mode`?

Answer (score 0):

thanks tobias

(smartparens-global-mode -1)

does the trick

Update:  This doesn't work. ( I checked the next day)
Still looking for an answer.

I can manually do M-x smarparens-mode 
after opening each file, which is cumbersome

Comment: Where did you put `(smartparens-global-mode -1)`?

Comment: its the last line in 

~/.emacs.d/personal/personal.el

Comment: I have reinstalled emacs and also restarted the brew emacs service

Comment: the problem appears sometimes. not always.